# PHP PDO Error 42000

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to insert data in a mysql table using PDO with PHP. I receive everytime the 42000 error and I can't understand why.
Here there is my code:

```
    $getOriginalOffer = $db->prepare("select * from original_offer where id = :id");
    $getOriginalOffer->bindParam(":id",$idOriginal);
    $getOriginalOffer->execute();
    $originalOffer = $getOriginalOffer->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $publishOfferQuery = "insert into published_offer (codice_onshop,nome,inbreve,anteprima,galleria1,galleria2,galleria3,galleria4,prezzo,tp_prezzo,bonus_usabile,proposta,condizioni,prenotare,categoria,description,keywords,valido_da,valido_a";
    $publishOfferQuery .= "values (:co,:no,:ib,:an,:g1,:g2,:g3,:g4,:pr,:tp,:bo,:pro,:con,:pre,:ca,:de,:ke,:da,:a)";
    $publishOffer = $db->prepare($publishOfferQuery);
    $publishOffer->bindParam(':co', $onshopCode);
    $publishOffer->bindParam(':no' ,$originalOffer['nome']);
    $publishOffer->bindParam(':ib' ,$originalOffer['inbreve']);
    $publishOffer->bindParam(':an' ,$originalOffer['anteprima']);
    $publishOffer->bindParam(':g1' ,$originalOffer['galleria1']);
    $publishOffer->bindParam(':g2' ,$originalOffer['galleria2']);
    $publishOffer->bindParam(':g3' ,$originalOffer['galleria3']);
    $publishOffer->bindParam(':g4' ,$originalOffer['galleria4']);
    $publishOffer->bindParam(':pr' ,$originalOffer['prezzo']);
    $publishOffer->bindParam(':tp' ,$originalOffer['tp_prezzo']);
    $publishOffer->bindParam(':bo' ,$originalOffer['bonus']);
    $publishOffer->bindParam(':pro',$originalOffer['proposta']);
    $publishOffer->bindParam(':con',$originalOffer['condizioni']);
    $publishOffer->bindParam(':pre',$originalOffer['prenotare']);
    $publishOffer->bindParam(':ca' ,$originalOffer['categoria']);
    $publishOffer->bindParam(':de' ,$originalOffer['description']);
    $publishOffer->bindParam(':ke' ,$originalOffer['keywords']);
    $publishOffer->bindParam(':da' ,$oggi);
    $publishOffer->bindParam(':a'  ,$a);
    if($publishOffer->execute()) {
        echo "<p style='color: red; font-weight: bold; text-align: center'>Operazione effettuata con successo. Attendi 5 secondi...</p>";
        sleep(5);
        header("location: ../elenco_offerte.php");
    }
```

I have also tried to send parameters with the function $quote, cause there are also html tags in these parameters, but it gives me:

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by
```

I'm quite desperate! How I can solve this?
Thanks before!

Comment: I think you have missed a `)` in `$publishOfferQuery`

Comment: @Mr.NaViD You're right =)

Comment: I think if you use a good IDE you can find these problems easily. :-)

Comment: @Mr.NaViD Like? I actually use Komodo Edit for PHP

Comment: try JetBrains PHPStorm.I found it excellent

Comment: @Mr.NaViD Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never close the parenthesis for the column delcarations.

```
 $publishOfferQuery = "insert into published_offer (codice_onshop,nome,inbreve,anteprima,galleria1,galleria2,galleria3,galleria4,prezzo,tp_prezzo,bonus_usabile,proposta,condizioni,prenotare,categoria,description,keywords,valido_da,valido_a"; <--- here
```

should be

```
 $publishOfferQuery = "insert into published_offer (codice_onshop,nome,inbreve,anteprima,galleria1,galleria2,galleria3,galleria4,prezzo,tp_prezzo,bonus_usabile,proposta,condizioni,prenotare,categoria,description,keywords,valido_da,valido_a)";
```

or in the next bit before the `values`...

```
$publishOfferQuery .= " ) values (:co,:no,:ib,:an,:g1,:g2,:g3,:g4,:pr,:tp,:bo,:pro,:con,:pre,:ca,:de,:ke,:da,:a)";
```

either or.

As is your query was

```
insert into published_offer 
(codice_onshop,nome,inbreve,anteprima,galleria1,galleria2,galleria3,galleria4,prezzo,tp_prezzo,bonus_usabile,proposta,condizioni,prenotare,categoria,description,keywords,valido_da,valido_a 
values (:co,:no,:ib,:an,:g1,:g2,:g3,:g4,:pr,:tp,:bo,:pro,:con,:pre,:ca,:de,:ke,:da,:a)
```

Comment: You're right... I was looking at code from more than 20 minutes... I hate these stupid errors. Thank you very much! When 10 minutes are passed I give you the right answer!

Answer (score 2):

You have to put `)` in the end of your MySQL query:

```
$publishOfferQuery = "insert into published_offer (codice_onshop,nome,inbreve,anteprima,galleria1,galleria2,galleria3,galleria4,prezzo,tp_prezzo,bonus_usabile,proposta,condizioni,prenotare,categoria,description,keywords,valido_da,valido_a");
```